# Font on the status bar

Tags: android, android-studio

I create 2 themes: light and dark and there was a problem with the light theme.

Tell me how to change the Font on the status bar? what attribute is responsible for this?
themes.xml:

```
<style name="Light" parent="Theme.Notepad">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/background</item> 
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
 </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the ActionBar? the status bar doesn't have any text except for the time, probably the operator name

Comment: @Zain Oh, there is no text, right, I mean the time and the wifi icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change textView textcolour which under the toolbar, from selected theme.

```
 <style name="Light" parent="Theme.Notepad">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/background</item> 
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
 </style>
  

<color name="textColour">@color/Black</color>//textViewColour for lightTheme
```

And also add same think in your darkTheme like :

```
  <color name="textColour">@color/White</color>
```

Then set your textView colour

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Keypad"
     android:textColor="@color/textColour"
     android:textSize="10sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Hope its work ...

Comment: I'm not talking about TextView, I meant the font in the status bar, where the time and the wifi icon are displayed. In the photo I highlighted what text you need

Answer (score 1):

Please use below line to change status bar color you can change true or false as per your them requirement

```
<!-- Status Bar Color -->
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
```